# FireDAC Missing Components in RAD Studio 10.2

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am sharing a project built in RAD Studio 10.2 that uses FireDAC components.

The projects datamodule contains a TFDConnection component that has the DriverName set to 'ODBC'.

The other user who is using <s>the exact</s> same version of RAD Studio (have compared all version information) cannot compile the project. They get the following compile error:

> Unit 'FireDAC.Phys.ODBC' not found.

If the other user looks on the tool palette under FireDAC Links there isn't a `TFDPhysODBCDriverLink` component available.

The one difference that I know about in the enviroment is I am running Win10 Pro, they are running Win10 Home. Could this cause the issue? If not, any ideas of what needs to be configured. Thanks.

Comment: Impossible to say (but I wouldn't blame OS).

Comment: Does the other user have any 3rd party components installed?

Comment: No 3rd party components installed.

Comment: On the other machine, in `Delphi | Component Palette`, how many FD Link components do you see on the `FireDAC Links tab`?

Comment: 14. They are missing all links below SQLite (DS,TBDX,Oracle,DB2, 
 Infx, MSSQL,TData, ASA, ODBC, & Mongo links are all missing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing, but the difference you are seeing between your machine and your colleague's
may be that you have different Delphi SKUs installed.  SKU = `stock-keeping unit`, which for Delphi traditionally includes the Pro, Enterprise and Architect retail packages.

> On the other machine, in Delphi | Component Palette, how many FD Link components do you see on the FireDAC Links tab?
>
> 14. They are missing all links below SQLite (DS,TBDX,Oracle,DB2, Infx, MSSQL,TData, ASA, ODBC, & Mongo links are all missing

Well, the Link components that you can see are all in the package `dclFireDAC250.Bpl`.  The ones which are missing are all in `dclFireDACEnt250.Bpl`.

So:

a) Does the other machine have the version of Delphi that includes `dclFireDACEnt250.Bpl`.  I haven't checked but I'm guessing `Ent` stands for Enterprise.  If not, that could be your answer. What is the Delphi SKU on the other machine?

b) If the other machine's Delphi SKU is supposed to include `dclFireDACEnt250.Bpl`, is that package on the other machine, and in the same folder as `dclFireDAC250.Bpl`?  If not, copy it there, and use `Component|Install packages` in the IDE to try and install it.

Btw, I checked and on a machine that I have which runs Win10 64-bit Home, The Enterprise SKU of Tokyo has the DS,TBDX,Oracle,DB2, Infx, MSSQL,TData, ASA, ODBC, & Mongo links on it.

Comment: You can see the current SKU in the Delphi Info dialog near the bottom, above the Windows version.

Comment: That's what I missed. They are running Professional and I am running Architect.

Comment: You will also have those components if you have the FireDac Client/Server Add-on Pack.